# Django inheritence question

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

some body please explain me the following i have two classes Userprofile and Staff.staff inherits userprofile

My Question is that if any entry has to be made to a staff  table .1.It would be mandatory to fill out the details of user profile right?

Please explain this inheritence.Thanks

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     emp_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     emp_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices = GENDER_CHOICES, null=False)
     date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
     address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=48)
     state = models.CharField(max_length=48)
     country = models.CharField(max_length=48)
     email_id = models.EmailField(blank=True)


  class Staff(UserProfile):
     role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
     designation = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True, null=True)
     education = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: The thing to remember is that there's no mechanism in Django to "promote" a `Profile` to a `Staff` if you use inheritance, but if `Staff` had a `OneToOneField` to `Profile` and no inheritance, then you could create a `Staff` that used an existing `Profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance you'll see that automatic One-to-One mappings are created. Therefore, an entry for UserProfile is saved, and an entry for Staff is saved with a OneToOne field that points to the UserProfile entry.

However, if you want Staff to just inherit all the fields, I'd recommend setting `abstract = True` in your UserProfile. This means that Staff inherits all those fields, but you can never create a UserProfile by itself (as described at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes )

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```